# Regular expression "^[a-zA-Z]" or "[^a-zA-Z]"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is there a difference between `^[a-zA-Z]` and `[^a-zA-Z]`?

When I check in C#,

```
Regex.IsMatch("t", "^[a-zA-Z]")  // Returns true (I think it's correct)

Regex.IsMatch("t", "[^a-zA-Z]")  // Returns false
```

There are a lot of web sites using `[^a-zA-Z]` for the alphabet. I'm not really sure which one is correct answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. I can see clearly now.

Comment: Glad the rain is gone!

Comment: BTW, C# doesn't have regular expressions. The .NET Framework does.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, the first means "match all strings that start with a letter", the second means "match all strings that contain a non-letter". The caret ("^") is used in two different ways, one to signal the start of the text, one to negate a character match inside square brackets.

Answer (score 23):

`^[a-zA-Z]` means any a-z or A-Z at the start of a line

`[^a-zA-Z]` means any character that IS NOT a-z OR A-Z

Comment: neither in a-z nor in A-Z

Answer (score 9):

There is a difference.

When the `^` character appears outside of `[]` matches the beginning of the line (or string).  When the `^` character appears inside the `[]`, it matches any character not appearing inside the `[]`.

Answer (score 7):

^ outside of the character class ("[a-zA-Z]") notes that it is the "begins with" operator.
^ inside of the character negates the specified class.

So, "^[a-zA-Z]" translates to "begins with character from a-z or A-Z", and "[^a-zA-Z]" translates to "is not either a-z or A-Z"

Here's a quick reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html