# How to validate user name with regular expression

Tags: javascript

I'd want to validate a username using a regular expression, however the expression I used worked well on [https://regexr.com/](https://regexr.com/%C2%A0)  but not in my code. I just want user can add only Alphanumeric and a space between them

```js
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/g;

function validate() {
  var input = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  if (input.match(letters)) {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "** Only alphabets are allowed in name.";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="fname">
<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Check">
<br>
<span id="name"></span>
```

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to limit user names, for example Peter O'Donelly-Smith might not be happy with that. *Why* do you need to limit user names? That might help us find a better solution for you.

Comment: I actually want to validate user names so that a user can input their names in the format "Ali Ahmed."

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't agree... messy username will be a bad idea. Will look bad for other users, and will be annoying, if someone will exploit it. Every decent service does limit user names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression "^\[a-zA-Z\]" or "\[^a-zA-Z\]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790813/regular-expression-a-za-z-or-a-za-z)

Comment: @FlashThunder Try telling that to anyone who wants their name to be represented correctly, but the system does not allow it.

Comment: @BismaAmjad There is a full stop, `.`, at the end of your example `Ali Ahmed.`. (There is a difference between using speech marks for speech, where following punctuation appears inside the quote marks, and quoting exact text for programming purposes.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton without any validation, you could use something like `<span>????</span>don't really care and it doesn't need to be evaluated as html to be annoying<script>whatever</script>` or even worse ... would you really like to have something like that in your db? I guarantee that there is no service that doesn't restrict the name string in this word, that has more than 100000 users. If there is, show me I'm wrong. Name it.

Comment: @FlashThunder It should not matter what is in the database, it will be HTML-encoded for display. *Won't it? ;)*

Comment: @AndrewMorton as I said in the name, it can't be evaluated, still a trash for other users, that don't want to see it. And there are a lot of people at least trying to exploit it. Even in SO you can't have such a name.

Comment: @BismaAmjad If you are looking at Persian names, then Mas'ud would be unlucky.

Comment: @FlashThunder There is an abundance of abhorrent ideas representable with just the letters a-z, which suggests that your point is not sufficiently well thought out if you are proposing that only allowing the characters in the range [A-Za-z] will inhibit them.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I agree that i should be extended, but not removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your current function is "finding alphanumeric characters". So, when you run `validate()`, it is returning either a valid Array, or `null`. To get spaces use `/^[\w\-\s]+$/` although this will return true for multiple spaces. I'm not sure your use case.

Unless you want to change your regex, you need to show your warning when `input.match()` returns a falsey value. To do this, Place `!` before your `input.match()` function

```js
var letters = /^[\w\-\s]+$/;

function validate() {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "";

  var input = document.getElementById("fname").value;

  if (!input.match(letters)) {
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "** Only alphabets are allowed in name.";
return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="fname">
<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Check">
<br>
<span id="name"></span>
```

Comment: Yeah, guys I should have read the question more specifically instead of just bug-fixing the existing code. I will update or remove my answer.

Comment: Also, is this duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283470/regex-for-allowing-alphanumeric-and-space ?